# My output have an extra 0 in it, why is that

Tags: c++

So I'm doing practice on leetcode and this is the question:

You are given two non-empty linked lists representing two non-negative 
integers. The digits are stored in reverse order and each of their nodes 
contain a single digit. Add the two numbers and return it as a linked list.

You may assume the two numbers do not contain any leading zero, except the 
number 0 itself.

Example:

Input: (2 -> 4 -> 3) + (5 -> 6 -> 4)

Output: 7 -> 0 -> 8

Explanation: 342 + 465 = 807.

```
/**
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 * struct ListNode {
 *     int val;
 *     ListNode *next;
 *     ListNode(int x) : val(x), next(NULL) {}
 * };
 */
```

And this is my solution:

```
class Solution {
public:
ListNode *addTwoNumbers(ListNode *l1, ListNode *l2) {
    vector<int> V1;
    vector<int> V2;
    int sum1 = 0;
    int sum2 = 0;
    ListNode *result = new ListNode(0);
    auto l0 = result;
    while(l1) {
        V1.push_back(l1->val);
        l1=l1->next;
    }

    for (auto it1 = V1.rbegin(); it1 != V1.rend(); it1++) {
        sum1 = sum1 * 10 + (*it1);
    }

    while(l2) {
        V2.push_back(l2->val);
        l2=l2->next;
    }

    for (auto it2 = V2.rbegin(); it2 != V2.rend(); it2++) {
        sum2 = sum2 * 10 + (*it2);
    }
    int sum3 = sum1 + sum2;
    while (sum3 !=0) {
        int extract = sum3 % 10;
        l0->next = new ListNode(extract);
        sum3 /= 10;
        l0=l0->next;
    }

    return result;


}
};
```

And when I ran it, there is always and extra 0 in my output, for example:

Your input
[7,2,7]  [2,4,2]

Your answer
[0,9,6,9]

Expected answer
[9,6,9]

I know there is a smarter way to solve this question, but I want to try to solve it in my way first

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Links to code screenshot or output are usually  not welcomed in SO. Put text in the body of question please. And provide [mcve] for your code.

Comment: gdb works really nice for c++ programms and can help you debug things like this.  It is also a really nice thing to know.

Comment: You probably don't like new ListNode(0) to initialize the result variable.  Consider that you know it always starts with 0, so don't output it.  A dummy node to initialize a list can produce much simpler code since you don't have to test for null and don't have to update the list head.  Best way to debug it is to start with 1+1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because you are creating the first node with 0. You have two solutions for that:

- Skip the first element at the end of the function (workaround):

  ```
  ListNode* aux = result;
  result = result->next;
  delete aux;
  return result;
  ```
- Not initialize the listnode to zero, use a nullpointer instead:

s

```
ListNode *result = nullptr;

// More code...

while (sum3 !=0) {
    int extract = sum3 % 10;
    if (l0 == nullptr) {
        result = new ListNode(extract);
        l0 = result;
    }
    else
        l0->next = new ListNode(extract);
    sum3 /= 10;
    l0=l0->next;
}
```

Ofc, there are better solutions. You could do the sum directly, without using extra vectors/memory.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an extra zero because you are doing `remainder` and `division` operation 1 time extra than required.  You have to modify the condition under last `while` loop.

```
while (sum3 > 9) {
    int extract = sum3 % 10;
    l0->next = new ListNode(extract);
    sum3 /= 10;
    l0=l0->next;
}
```